# How can the symmetric group $S_3$ be represented as $\{1, x, x^2, y, xy, x^2y\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

On page 42 in his book Algebra, Artin begins describing the symmetric group $S_3$. He claims the six elements of the group are $\{1,x,x^2,y,xy,x^2y\}$. I don't understand how he got these elements.
How did he get these 6 elements?

Comment: I define S_3 as the set of all permutations on a set of 3 elements.

Comment: You do know that there are $3! = 6$ such permutations, right? (That will confirm the number of elements in the set, for starters)

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I'm just confused as to why he is representing each element as a power of x and y.

Comment: Note that $\{1, x, x^2, y, xy, x^2y\}=D_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=(123), y=(23)$.  That is, $x$ is a $3$ cycle and $y$ a $2$ cycle, or transposition.

Comment: This still doesn't explain how the last element is x^2y

Comment: Well, $x^2=(132)$.  So $x^2y=(132)(23)=(13)$.  Play around with it a little to get a feel for it.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: You;re quite weldome.

Answer (score 0):

The group $S_3$ has $6$ elements: the identity, $(1\ \ 2)$, $(1\ \ 3)$, $(2\ \ 3)$, $(1\ \ 2\ \ 3)$, and $(1\ \ 3\ \ 2)$. Now, just let $x=(1\ \ 2\ \ 3)$ and let $y=(1\ \ 2)$.

Comment: I think you switched $x$ and $y$; the way you have it, $x^2=1$

Comment: Sure! Thank you. I have edited my answer.